# SendPrivateMessage Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I would like to ask how can I invoke the Send Private Message in Xamarin below is the example I made.

Please check above code, I don't know what mistake I have done. moreover I'm using online server
Please Help...

```
public void Connect(string userName)
{

   var id = Context.ConnectionId;

   if (ConnectedUsers.Count(x => x.ConnectionId == id) == 0)
   {

       ConnectedUsers.Add(new UserDetail { ConnectionId = id, UserName = userName });

       // send to caller
       Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, userName, ConnectedUsers, CurrentMessage);

       // send to all except caller client
       Clients.AllExcept(id).onNewUserConnected(id, userName);

   }

}

public void SendPrivateMessage(string toUserId, string message)
{
string fromUserId = Context.ConnectionId;
var toUser = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == toUserId) ;
var fromUser = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == fromUserId);

   if (toUser != null && fromUser!=null)
   {
       // send to
       Clients.Client(toUserId).sendPrivateMessage(fromUserId, fromUser.UserName, message);

       // send to caller user
       Clients.Caller.sendPrivateMessage(toUserId, fromUser.UserName, message);
   }

}
```

Here in Xamarin
here in Xamarin application:

```
var hubconnection=new HubConnection("");
var chatHubProvxy=hubconnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
chatHubProxy.On<string,string>("sendPrivateMessage",(user,message)=>
{
this.RunOnUiThread(()=>
{
TextView txtmsg=new TextView(this);
txtmessage.LayoutParameters=newLinearLyout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent){
TopMargin=10,
Gravity=GravityFlags.Right
};
});
});
try{
await hubconnection.Start();
}
catch{}
Btnsend.Click+=async(o,e2)=>{
var message=EdtTxt.Text;
await chatHubProxy.Invoke("Connect",new object[]{userfrom});
await chatHubProxy.Invoke("sendPrivateMessage",new object[]{userto, message});
}};
```

Comment: Is this Signalr ?  it might be worth mentioning it

Comment: Yes it is signalr